# Multiple riddles

Tags: riddle

Riddle #1

> What is a bear without an ear?

Riddle #2

> What has a bed, but never sleeps, and has a mouth, but never eats?

Riddle #3

> We see it in one, ten, hundred but not in thousand days. What is it?

Riddle #4

> Why did the phone needed glasses?

Riddle #5

> What costs nothing, but it is hard to find, and can easily be lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> a b(ee)

2.

> a river

3.

> the letter e

4.

> It lost its contacts. Or it's an iPhone (eye)

5.

> Time

Comment: Almost! You got the fifth one wrong

Comment: Close! But it makes sense

Comment: I just saw Timwi's answer, and I agree, that fits a bit better.

Answer (score 3):

For #5, others have suggested

> Time

but I think an equally valid answer is

> Friendship

Comment: yes!!! It is. Im finally happy that you got it

Answer (score 2):

The first three are old chestnuts:

> 1. A bee (B).
>  2. A river.
>  3. The letter E.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me from my younger days!

> 4. He had a small i (iPhone)
>  5. Time

Comment: Got the fifth one wrong, but i guess it makes sense...